# Using Apollo to mix local and remote fields using the @client directive

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I'm using `apollo-client@2.6.10` in a VueJS application.

I have a `user` type that has (until recently) used local-only fields. Here is the local query and corresponding mutation:

```
query currentUserQuery  {
  user @client {
    id
    email
    emailVerified
    displayName
  }
}

mutation setCurrentUser($id: ID!, $email: String!, $emailVerified: Boolean!, $displayName: String) {
  update_current_user(
    id: $id,
    email: $email,
    emailVerified: $emailVerified,
    displayName: $displayName
) @client
}
```

And I also have a corresponding resolver for the mutation:

```js
resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    update_current_user: (_, { id, email, emailVerified, displayName }, { cache }) => {
      const data = cache.readQuery({ query: currentUserQuery })
      const user = {
        __typename: 'User',
        id,
        email,
        emailVerified,
        displayName
      }
      data.user = user
      cache.writeData({ data })
      return user
    }
}
```

So far, so good!

What I'd like to do now is mix in some additional fields from the remote api. So, I modified the query as such:

```
query currentUserQuery  {
  user {
    id @client
    email @client
    emailVerified @client
    displayName @client
    tier {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I also updated the initial cache object written `cache.writeQuery` to include placeholder `tier` data.

But no matter how I try to wrangle this, the tier is always the initialised `null` value, and after inspecting network traffic I can see that the remote fields are not being fetched.

Should I be doing something different with resolvers? I've tried using local query resolvers for the local fields (instead of relying on direct fetches from the cache) to no avail.

After reading through the v2 docs and trying a variety of different approaches I'm at a loss to understand what's not working here.

Help greatly appreciated!